Kafka. Partition leader election
Does kafka automatically perform unclean leader election for partitions?
I have topic
./kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server XXX --describe --topic my-topic
Topic: my-topic    TopicId: q7VUw5a6T_youSEL3WPLGQ PartitionCount: 60      ReplicationFactor: 6    Configs: min.insync.replicas=1,segment.bytes=1073741824,unclean.leader.election.enable=true
        Topic: my-topic    Partition: 0    Leader: none    Replicas: 6,5,4,3,2,1   Isr: 6
        Topic: my-topic    Partition: 1    Leader: none    Replicas: 5,6,4,3,2,1   Isr: 6
        Topic: my-topic    Partition: 2    Leader: none    Replicas: 4,5,6,3,2,1   Isr: 6
        Topic: my-topic    Partition: 3    Leader: none    Replicas: 6,5,4,3,2,1   Isr: 6
        Topic: my-topic    Partition: 4    Leader: none    Replicas: 5,6,4,3,2,1   Isr: 6
        Topic: my-topic    Partition: 5    Leader: none    Replicas: 4,5,6,3,2,1   Isr: 6
        Topic: my-topic    Partition: 6    Leader: none    Replicas: 6,5,4,3,2,1   Isr: 6

I can run script kafka-leader-election.sh with option --election-type UNCLEAN. It helps - after that partitions have leader and ISR list contains all available replicas. But my question is about automatic leader election - without manual intervention - is it possible? Or, maybe, unclean leader election is too dangerious and I can perform it only manually?
